# Load testing AWS SDK client

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-net

What is the recommended way to performance test AWS SDK clients?  I'm basically just listing/describing resources and would like to see what happens when I query 10k objects.  Does AWS provide some type of mock API, or do I really need to request 10k of each type of resource to do this?

I can of course mock in at least two levels:

1. SDK: I wrap the SDK with my own interfaces and create mocks.  This doesn't exercise the SDK's JSON to objects code and my mocks affect the AppDomain with additional memory, garbage collection, etc.
2. REST API: As I understand it the SDKs are just wrappers to the REST API (hence the HTTP response codes shown in the objects.  It seems I can configure the SDK to go to custom endpoints.
   This isolates the mocks from the main AppDomain and is more representative, but of course I'm still making some assumptions about response time, limits, etc.

Besides the above taking a long time to implement, I would like to make sure my code won't fail at scale, either locally or at AWS.  The only way I see to guarantee that is creating (and paying for) the resources at AWS.  Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you query 10k or more objects you'll have to deal with:

1. **Pagination** - the API usually returns only a limited number of items per call, providing `NextToken` for the next call.
2. **Rate Limiting** - if you hammer some AWS APIs too much they'll rate limit you which the SDK will probably report as some kind of *Rate Limit Exceeded Exception*.
3. **Memory usage** - hopefully you don't collect all the results in the memory before processing. Process them as they arrive to conserve your operating memory.

Other than that I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Update: Also check out [**Moto**](https://github.com/spulec/moto) - the AWS mocking library (for Python) that can also run in a *standalone mode* for use with other languages. However as with any mocking it may not behave 100% the same as the real thing, for instance around the *Rate Limiting* behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I've considered those. My question is really around how to test a realistic scenario, but ideally not having to spin up 10k of each resource (which would require a support ticket and may not be approved). Basically, can I stand up a simulated environment that I can query and is representative of a real environment? Does AWS or anyone else offer something similar? Rate limiting is actually a perfect example my own mocking may not have accounted for if I didn't know ahead of time that could happen.

Comment: @NelsonRothermel Check out [**Moto**](https://github.com/spulec/moto) - the AWS mocking library (for Python) that can also run in a *standalone mode* for use with other languages. However as with any mocking it may not behave 100% the same as the real thing, for instance around the *Rate Limiting* behaviour.